# CUDNN Installation

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I am trying to install CUDNN to use tensorflow with GPU support on my Macbook Pro. After downloading cudnn from NVDIA website, these are all the instructions i could find:

OS X

```
cd <installpath>
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Add <installpath> to your build and link process by adding -I<installpath> to your compile
line and -L<installpath> -lcudnn to your link line.
```

While, the first step is really straightforward, what is the meaning of second statement and how do I finish the second step?
Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify CuDNN installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was stuck at the same place and what I found was that the cudnn archive basically had just two library files a : .h and .so files. so I figured it was best to put them someplace that is already looked at and I found this :

```
Untar the folder and copy the necessary files to the existing cuda 
library we installed earlier.

tar -xzvf cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz
cp cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

so I guess u should find an equivalent for mac

source:

### https://medium.com/@acrosson/installing-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-keras-69bbf33dce8a

Comment: This worked for me on my macbook pro (OSX 10.11.6). I just copied the handful of files to their respective directories in the main CUDA installation. For me (using defaults), these were the dirs,

'/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin'
'/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib'