# tensorflow-gpu and cuDNN not properly installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, cudnn

I installed CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64) with NVidia Geforce GTX 950M (driver 381) in an ASUS K501UX laptop. After `CUDA` installation, I'm able to run `deviceQuery` and `bandwidthTest`, according to [this doc](http://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/gpu/nvidia/verify_cuda_install.html).

The cuDNN 5.1 downloaded was a `.deb` package and installed automatically. **However**, there is no `cudnn.h` in `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/`, and no `libcudnn` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory. [this validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation) indicate cuDNN is probably not properly installed.

Tensorflow-gpu did not run, so either `tensorflow` or `cuDNN` is problematic. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The key is to keep `cuDNN` version **compatible with device**. I should have downloaded `cuDNN` v5.1 library for Linux in `.tar.gz` format, and copy files into the corresponding directories.