# Install gpu version tensorflow with older version CUDA and cuDNN

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

Currently, I need to install gpu version tensorflow on a machine that existing an older version CUDA and cuDNN, and my question is how can I get it done without re-installing CUDA and cuDNN since other package (see pytorch) need it.

Comment: The formulation in this Q&A pair is unclear. Therefore, the as duplicate marked Q&A pair should instead be used. In a shorter time it was able to attract more views. Therefore, it is more visible to the community. I advise to use the duplicate as the primary Q&A pair instead or make this Q&A more clear (e.g. the used language/grammar is bad and additionally, the link below does not point to the table directly. Also which OS compatibility is shown below?).
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible/50622526#50622526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check CUDA version with below command according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version).

```
$ nvcc --version
```

Check cuDNN version with below command according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation).

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
```

Choose tensorflow-gpu version according to [this post](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding a canonical Q&A pair for this. [SO] gets bombarded with questions about this and it would be good to have this as an up to date reference which we can use to close the many duplicates that we will undoubtedly get in the future.

Comment: Good to know :)  @talonmies

Comment: The formulation in this Q&A pair is unclear. Therefore, the as duplicate marked Q&A pair should instead be used. In a shorter time it was able to attract more views. Therefore, it is more visible to the community. I advise to use the duplicate as the primary Q&A pair instead or make this Q&A more clear (e.g. the used language/grammar is bad and additionally, the link below does not point to the table directly. Also which OS compatibility is shown below?).
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible/50622526#50622526

Comment: the second command return nothing on ubuntu 20.04