# cudnn error :: CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (1 vs. 0) CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: nvidia, openpose

I am trying to install a open-source software "openpose" for which I needed to install cuda, cudnn and nvidia drivers. Output of nvidia-smi is :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.59       Driver Version: 440.59       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    107MiB /  2004MiB |      7%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1513      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            63MiB |
|    0      1698      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          41MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And output of `cat /usr/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2` gives:

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
```

After successfull installations of all the above softwares and libraries, I finally ran openpose
with:

```
./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --video examples/media/video.avi
```

But the output was:

```
Starting OpenPose demo...
Configuring OpenPose...
Starting thread(s)...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.
F0214 01:02:35.327615  3433 cudnn_conv_layer.cpp:53] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (1 vs. 0)  CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fabb8f390cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fabb8f3af33  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fabb8f38c28  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fabb8f3b999  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fabb89459d3  caffe::CuDNNConvolutionLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fabb8a42308  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fabb8a441e0  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fabbaa2ccaa  op::NetCaffe::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa500a1  op::addCaffeNetOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa51518  op::PoseExtractorCaffe::netInitializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa57163  op::PoseExtractorNet::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa4be61  op::PoseExtractor::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa46a51  op::WPoseExtractor<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa8aff1  op::Worker<>::initializationOnThreadNoException()
    @     0x7fabbaa8b120  op::SubThread<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa8d2d8  op::Thread<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fabbaa8d4a7  op::Thread<>::threadFunction()
    @     0x7fabba32566f  (unknown)
    @     0x7fabb9a476db  start_thread
    @     0x7fabb9d8088f  clone
Aborted
```

I have gone through a lot of online discussions but could not figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

I have been having the same problem with CUDNN.

Although not ideal, I have been running without CUDNN. In cmake-gui uncheck USE_CUDNN and then compile. When running openpose I have also had to reduce -net_resolution.

For example:  ./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin -net_resolution 256x192
The greater the resolution the slower the FPS though.

Comment: i guess the last resort is to launch tensorflow from inside the docker container

Comment: openpose uses pytorch/caffe, not tensorflow ;). One way is to downgrade driver + cuda + cudnn combo to match openpose requirements.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/2166)  your gpu may lack in memory space, whereas in respect to [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudnn-conv-layer-cpp-53-check-failed-status-cudnn-status-success-4-vs-0-cudnn-status-internal-error/56243) you may need to add a different version of `cudnn` (to install you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978616/15842840)).

if you don't care about the response time of your application, most of the times you may build your app to run on the CPU instead, so as to completely avoid such issues..