# Could not find any cudnn.h matching version '8' in any subdirectory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cudnn

For some specific purpose, I am building TF 1.14 **from source** with CUDA 11.1, CUDNN 8.0.4 & TensorRT 7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 but getting an error:-

[image]

I have verified that CUDNN is installed at /usr/include/cudnn.h and following [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation#:%7E:text=Install%20CuDNN&text=For%20most%20people%2C%20it%20will,check%20it%20with%20which%20nvcc%20.) I have copy pasted cudnn.h file at /usr/local/cuda/ and "libcudnn8_8.0.4.30-1+cuda11.1_amd64.deb" , "libcudnn8-dev_8.0.4.30-1+cuda11.1_amd64.deb" files to to /usr/local/cuda.  Can anyone please help me?

As a side note, which I think probably not the cause of this issue; there are two CUDNN and CUDA versions installed on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Robert, CUDA 11.1, CUDNN 8.0.4  are not compatible with TF 1.14. First I would recommend you upgrade to tensorflow 2 but it is not necessary. I found it best to install tensorflow using  Conda if you have Anaconda installed. Reason is conda will install the right versions of the cuda toolkit and cudnn automatically. Pip does not do that and you manually have to download the right versions and change the path environment variable to point to the directories where you placed them etc. So first I would uninstall tensorflow, then reinstall it with conda. If you need further information there is a good guide located [here.](https://medium.com/swlh/cuda-compatible-tensorflow-installation-in-windows-cad02c85a0ef)

Comment: Gerry, even if CUDA 11.1, CUDNN 8.0.4 is incompatible with TF 1.14, does this specific error popped-up due to that? The error indicates it is unable to locate the CUDNN file. If there would be an incompatibility issue then maybe an error will generate during compilation. What do you think about it?