# How do I verify if CUDNN installed correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, cuda, cudnn

I have tried this command
`cat /usr/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`
but it does not show anything.

I am also trying to verify by the way given at Nvidia website but
`cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7/ $HOME`
it says these are the same file.

I am new to ubuntu and also the first time using tensorflow/pytorch GPU. Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: check in `/usr/local/cuda/include` (assuming you've installed cuda).

Comment: Yeah it is there. And my tensorflow worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify CuDNN installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation)