# How can I determine the full CUDA version + subversion?

Tags: cuda, version

CUDA distributions on Linux used to have a file named `version.txt` which read, e.g.:

```
CUDA Version 10.2.89
```

which is quite useful. However, as of CUDA 11.1, this file no longer exists.

How can I determine, on Linux and from the command line, and inspecting `/path/to/cuda/toolkit`, which exact version I'm looking at? Including the subversion?

Comment: `nvcc --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer due to @RobertCrovella's comment)

This will do the trick:

```bsh
/path/to/cuda/toolkit/bin/nvcc --version | egrep -o "V[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" | cut -c2-
```

And of course, for the CUDA version currently chosen and configured to be used, just take the `nvcc` that's on the path:

```bsh
nvcc --version | egrep -o "V[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" | cut -c2-
```

For example: You would get `11.2.67` for the download of CUDA 11.2 which was available this week on the NVIDIA website.

The full `nvcc --version` output would be:

```bsh
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:08:53_PST_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following python code works well for both Windows and Linux and I have tested it with a variety of CUDA (8-11.2, most of them).

It searches for the cuda_path, via a series of guesses (checking environment vars, nvcc locations or default installation paths) and then grabs the CUDA version from the output of `nvcc --version`. Doesn't use @einpoklum's style regexp, it simply assumes there is only one `release`  string within the output of `nvcc --version`, but that can be simply checked.

You can also just use the first function, if you have a known path to query.

Adding it as an extra of @einpoklum answer, does the same thing, just in python.

[From TIGRE.](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/master/Python/setup.py)

```
import glob
import os
from os.path import join as pjoin
import subprocess
import sys


def get_cuda_version(cuda_home):
    """Locate the CUDA version
    """
    version_file = os.path.join(cuda_home, "version.txt")
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(version_file):
            with open(version_file) as f:
                version_str = f.readline().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
                return version_str.split(" ")[2][:4]
        else:
            version_str = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(cuda_home,"bin","nvcc"),"--version"])
            version_str=str(version_str).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
            idx=version_str.find("release")
            return version_str[idx+len("release "):idx+len("release ")+4]
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot read cuda version file") 
def locate_cuda():
    """Locate the CUDA environment on the system

    Returns a dict with keys 'home', 'include' and 'lib64'
    and values giving the absolute path to each directory.

    Starts by looking for the CUDA_HOME or CUDA_PATH env variable. If not found, everything
    is based on finding 'nvcc' in the PATH.
    """
    # Guess #1
    cuda_home = os.environ.get('CUDA_HOME') or os.environ.get('CUDA_PATH')
    if cuda_home is None:
        # Guess #2
        try:
            which = 'where' if IS_WINDOWS else 'which'
            nvcc = subprocess.check_output(
                [which, 'nvcc']).decode().rstrip('\r\n')
            cuda_home = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(nvcc))
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            # Guess #3
            if IS_WINDOWS:
                cuda_homes = glob.glob(
                    'C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v*.*')
                if len(cuda_homes) == 0:
                    cuda_home = ''
                else:
                    cuda_home = cuda_homes[0]
            else:
                cuda_home = '/usr/local/cuda'
            if not os.path.exists(cuda_home):
                cuda_home = None
    version = get_cuda_version(cuda_home)
    cudaconfig = {'home': cuda_home,
                  'include': pjoin(cuda_home, 'include'),
                  'lib64': pjoin(cuda_home, pjoin('lib', 'x64') if IS_WINDOWS else 'lib64')}
    if not all([os.path.exists(v) for v in cudaconfig.values()]):
        raise EnvironmentError(
            'The CUDA  path could not be located in $PATH, $CUDA_HOME or $CUDA_PATH. '
            'Either add it to your path, or set $CUDA_HOME or $CUDA_PATH.')

    return cudaconfig, version


CUDA, CUDA_VERSION = locate_cuda()
```

Comment: I am sure this code can be improved, but for now, it does the job :). Feel free to edit/improve the post.

Comment: Ander, note I asked about determining the version of a CUDA installation which is not the system default, i.e. taking a specific root path. So only the `get_cuda_version()` part is relevant to this question. Also, it seems you're expecting the CUDA compiler to be named `nvcc.exe`... or am I wrong?

Comment: @einpoklum absolutely! But the first part needs the `cuda_path` to run, so I decided that the second part *may* be of interest to future reader.  Indeed, it expects an .exe, and that is a mistake... Should just be `nvcc` (or be OS specific, testing).