# I cannot get Tensorflow 2.0 to work on my GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I have been writing programs in Tensorflow on my computer, which uses Linux Mint.  For whatever reason I can't get Tensorflow to operate on my GPU.

> 2021-04-26 15:46:11.462612: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 2021-04-26 15:46:11.462650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

I know for a fact that I have CUDA installed, because for PyTorch, the GPU works fine:

```
mydevice = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(mydevice)
```

yields

> cuda

Also, I ran a program with tensorflow, and I get:

```
START TIME:  Mon Apr 26 16:34:24 2021
2021-04-26 16:34:24.499178: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-04-26 16:34:24.499862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526372: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.56GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 3.82GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 119.24GiB/s
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526900: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526986: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.527069: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.528676: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-04-26 16:34:24.528994: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-04-26 16:34:24.530990: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-04-26 16:34:24.531125: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.531230: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.531245: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-04-26 16:34:24.531641: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-04-26 16:34:24.532140: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-04-26 16:34:24.532178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-04-26 16:34:24.532192: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      
2021-04-26 16:34:24.592917: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-04-26 16:34:24.593369: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2400000000 Hz
```

I installed tensorflow on anaconda using conda, though the build is from PyPi, I believe.  Please let me know your suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: What version of CUDA do you have? See this answer if you need help checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your error logs that tensorflow IS picking up your GPU (GTX 1650). However, the problem is that the `cudatoolkit and the cudnn version` could be incompatible with your tensorflow version. TF is rather specific with these requirements. The error lines that you need to take note are these:

```
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526900: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library **'libcudart.so.11.0'**; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.526986: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library **'libcublas.so.11'**; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.527069: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library **'libcublasLt.so.11'**; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.528676: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10

2021-04-26 16:34:24.531125: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library **'libcusparse.so.11'**; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-26 16:34:24.531230: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library **'libcudnn.so.8'**; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The latest tensorflow release tensorflow-2.4.0 ([See full table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)) only plays nicely with : cuDNN 8.0 and CUDA 11.0 versions.
(though newer versions of these have already been released -- you might need to check your version, I think you might be using CUDA 10).

I would suggest having a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) (older but the commands and principles still apply).

---

### For conda, and creating a new environment for TensorFlow:

1. Make a yaml file ([example yaml file for tensorflow](https://gist.github.com/dcstang/a07823655c6ea85e53ae181e4de5b8b1))
2. Create a [new environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) for Tensorflow using above yaml file

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

3. Activate your new environment

`conda activate tensorflow_env_388`

Nb. A fresh environment will avoid any conflicting packages.

---

### To troubleshoot and check what is currently installed

`conda list cudnn`

```
# packages in environment at /rds/general/user/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_env_388:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudnn                     7.0.5.39             ha5ca753_1    conda-forge
```

`conda list cudatoolkit`

Then cudnn/cuda install as necessary

`conda install cudatoolkit=11.0`

`conda install cudnn=8.0`

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply.  I'm running conda install cudatoolkit=11.0, but I keep getting "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages."  At this point the upgrade basically stops working.

Comment: There could be conflicts with other packages, and it would probably be a bit cumbersome to troubleshoot everything. As with my post, I suggest that you create a fresh new conda environment for tensorflow. One of the easset ways is [by using a yml file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file). Will add full instructions into my post above on this.

Answer (score 0):

What channel did you install it from?  If you are using the default channel, you have to specify the GPU version of tensorflow.

```
conda install tensorflow=2.4.*=gpu* -c anaconda
```