# Which version of pytorch should be installed for cuda12.2, why can't I find it on the official website?

Tags: pytorch

May I ask which version of pytorch should be installed for cuda12.2, why can't I find it on the official website?

[image]

This is a screenshot of the CUDA version of my server, can you help me?

[image]

This is a screenshot of the official website, and the version of cuda12.2 cannot be found

The previous version of the server was CUDA 10.0. I did not know how to upgrade the version. I need to change the version of pytorch. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: As seen here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/RELEASE.md
the newest stable version of PyTorch supports CUDA 11.7 & CUDNN 8.5.0.96. Currently CUDA 12.2 is not implemented. 
Also, please check your actual CUDA version using the `nvcc --version` command

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information like terminal output. Copy the text itself into a code block instead. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: The `CUDA Version` in the top right of the `nvidia-smi` output is the **maximum** CUDA version supported by the installed driver. It has nothing to do with the version of one or more installed CUDA Toolkits, which is why @iregular asks for the "actual CUDA version". See [How to get the CUDA version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version)